# TO get the Distinct decendant nodes by filtering the attribute value of the node

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<states_Page>
  <states>
  <state id="sectionenable" systemstate="n" focuscontrol="" default="">
  </state>
</states>
<states>
  <state id="controlenable" systemstate="n" focuscontrol="" default="">
  </state>
</states>
<states>
  <state id="controldisable" systemstate="n" focuscontrol="" default="">
  </state>
</states>
<states>
  <state id="controldisable2" systemstate="n" focuscontrol="" default="">
  </state>
</states>
<states>
  <state id="sectionenable2" systemstate="n" focuscontrol="" default="">
  </state>
</states>
<states>
  <state id="sectionenable" systemstate="n" focuscontrol="" default="">
  </state>
</states>
</states_Page>
```

there are 6 elements under the root element..

i want the nodes which having a distinct Attribute name.

so i need to return only 5 elements those having a distinct attribute values.
i have tried a  linq but it returns the distinct attribute value alone..but i need the whole Element.

```
var ds = (from ele in root.Elements("states").Elements("state") 
          select ele.Attribute("id").Value).Distinct();
```

so help me to get the whole element in a **single line of query.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = xdoc.Root.Descendants("states")
                      .GroupBy(x => x.Element("state").Attribute("id").Value)
                      .Select(x => x.First());
```

If you want to fetch the elements instead of nodes, you can use `anonymous` types like this:-

```
var result = xdoc.Root.Descendants("states")
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Element("state").Attribute("id").Value)
                  .Select(x =>
                      {
                         var firstNode = x.First().Element("state");
                         return new
                         {
                            StateId = firstNode.Attribute("id").Value,
                            SystemState = firstNode.Attribute("systemstate").Value,
                            Focuscontrol = firstNode.Attribute("focuscontrol").Value,
                            Default = firstNode.Attribute("default").Value
                          };
                       });
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul..Your First Solution Working Fine..:)

Comment: @Raji - You're welcome. As a newbie to SO, i would suggest to go through this link - 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and accept the answer if that "Helped" :)